# Coverage only reported of karma-test-shim (Electron/Angular2/SystemJS)

Tags: angular, karma-runner, electron, karma-coverage

All my tests run and pass successfully. But I keep getting either 0% coverage, or coverage of my karma-test-shim.js that launches the tests and their source files via SystemJS. I have tried using karma-coverage as a preprocessor in various ways as well, sometimes it pre-processes the spec.ts files, sometimes the ts files, sometimes the app directory, sometimes the js files or spec.js files. I use the Electron browser to load a require shim in the karma-test-shim.js file, as this is an app with plenty of system-level operations using node modules like fs, path, etc. I use SystemJS for the app and tests (no Webpack!).

This test setup, minus Electron browser and the require shim, is similar to my setup: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/karma.conf.js

Here is my karma.conf.js file.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: 'src/', // all the files in the files config  parameter, are searched for relative to this path

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: files, // this has all files needed

        reporters: ['spec', 'coverage'], //report to console

        port: 9876,

        colors: true,

        browsers: ['Electron'],

        singleRun: true 
    })
}
```

Comment: I don't see you have set up Preprocessor config entry. Mention your source files there. It should work.                                 e.g. preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },